# Finger detection and removal in document image

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, detection

I'd like to detect fingers in the image and remove them for book scanning.
I have searched for finger detection and object removal projects but none of them could easily be applied or the results were not good. So, I might have to start writing my own code..

Could you recommend useful algorithms for the below items?
I think,

1) Drawing a contour (including shadows)

2) Select the finger region

3) Context-aware-fill where the finger was

I tried,
https://github.com/VPanjeta/Deep-Object-Removal

Thanks in advance

[Finger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fNGW.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.color segmentation for selecting finger
2.clear border (with finger) like Matlab imclearborder. https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imclearborder.html

Comment: They look promising. Thanks!